# Using Count in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I am trying to use the count function , this is what it looks like :

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(Live) as c FROM tapplicant WHERE CompletedDate >= CURDATE() ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo  $row['c'] ;
```

How do i conver this using the cakePHP way ? , i have tryed :

```
$count = $this->Article->find('count', 
                                    array('conditions' => array('Tapplicant.Live')));
```

Then to view the value of $count :

```
<?php echo $count ?>
```

I have tryed :

```
        $this->Tapplicant = array(
    'c' => 'COUNT(*)',
);
$options = array(
    'fields' => array(
        'Tapplicant.c',
    ),
);
$data = $this->find('all', $options);
   $this->set('data', $data );
```

Basically im just trying to count the value of tapplicant.Live , there are 5 records in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the conditions array like this:-

```
$count = $this->Article->find(
    'count', 
    array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Live >=' => 'CURDATE()'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Hi @drmonkeyninja , thanks once again , and Miam84 that worked as well. I have a db table tapplicant , but it always seems to look for tapplicants , it adds a 's' all the time.

Answer (score 2):

You almost have it. In your condition, the value array should have 2 fields. 1st the column name, 2nd the value of the condition.

Considering you've binded correctly the Tapplicant table to your Article model :

```
$count = $this->Article->find('count', array('conditions' => array('Live >=' => 'CURDATE()' )));
```

Or just this, if you want to count all lines :

```
$count = $this->Article->find('count');
```

Comment: `i=0; i++; echo i;` for Correct answer !

Comment: With this : $count = $this->Tapplicant->find('count', array('conditions' => array('Live >=', 'CURDATE()' ))); i get the following error : SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `mdxexplo_cak3`.`tapplicants` AS `Tapplicant` WHERE Live >= AND CURDATE()

Comment: I need to count the value records in table : tapplicants.Live . each record has a value of 1 in so , it should equal '5'

Comment: my bad sorry. I wrote a comma as separator but it should be `=>`. I've edited my anwser.